# JAVAFX: TableView get multiple selection data

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have a TableView with some columns. It has multiple row selection support. What I want is get all the selected data.

**I know how to get single selected data.**

[image]

See the image. I want those 3 selected cell's data.

***Controller***

```
/*********************
     * TABLE ITEMS
     *********************/
    @FXML
    private TableView<DailySalesTableData> table;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<DailySalesTableData, String> dateColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<DailySalesTableData, String> nameColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<DailySalesTableData, String> addressColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<DailySalesTableData, String> productColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<DailySalesTableData, Double> quantityColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<DailySalesTableData, Double> priceColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<DailySalesTableData, Double> totalColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<DailySalesTableData, Double> depositColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<DailySalesTableData, Double> restColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<DailySalesTableData, String> checkColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<DailySalesTableData, Integer> transColumn;

private ObservableList<DailySalesTableData> tableData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1){
        dateColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData->new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cellData.getValue().getdate()));
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData->new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cellData.getValue().getName()));
        addressColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData->new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cellData.getValue().getAddress()));
        productColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData->new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cellData.getValue().getProduct()));
        quantityColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData->new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<Double>(cellData.getValue().getQuantity()));
        priceColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData->new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<Double>(cellData.getValue().getRate()));
        totalColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData->new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<Double>(cellData.getValue().getTotalPrice()));
        depositColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData->new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<Double>(cellData.getValue().getDeposit()));
        restColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData->new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<Double>(cellData.getValue().getRest()));
        transColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData->new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<Integer>(cellData.getValue().getTrans()));
        checkColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData->new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cellData.getValue().getStatus()));
        table.setItems(getPersonData());


        table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
        table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

    }

    public ObservableList<DailySalesTableData> getPersonData() {
        return tableData;
    }
```

How to do that?

Comment: Can you show how your table and columns are set up (post the code)? You have cell selection enabled, as well as multiple selection, is that right?

Comment: Yes. You are right. Let me update the post.

Comment: @James_D I've updated the post with table code.

Comment: Your screenshot isn't really very representative of the general situation. You have 11 columns with three different data types represented. In general, the user can select an arbitrary combination of any cells. What do you actually want to do in the situation where you have multiple data types (e.g. some string cells, some integer cells, some double cells) selected? What do you want to do with these data?

Comment: Have you tried the `getSelectedCells()` method of the `SelectionModel`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a list of all the positions in the table that are selected by the (fairly badly named) `getSelectedCells()` method in the selection model. This returns a list of `TablePosition` objects (so it would really make more sense to have called it `getSelectedPositions()` or some such, but anyway...); from each of those you can get the table column (either as a `TableColumn` object with `getTableColumn()` or as an index, with `getColumn()`), and the row as an index with `getRow()`.

To get the data is still a little tricky. In your example, you have columns with multiple data types (`String`, `Double`, and `Integer` columns) and of course you can have an arbitrary collection of any cells selected. So you could write code something like this:

```
for (TablePosition<DailySalesTableData, ?> pos : table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells()) {

    int row = pos.getRow();
    DailySalesTableData data = table.getItems().get(row);
    if (pos.getTableColumn() == dateColumn) {
        String date = data.getDate();
        // process date...
    } else if (pos.getTableColumn() == quantityColumn) {
        double quantity = data.getQuantity() ;
        // process quantity...
    }
    // etc etc etc
}
```

That's a little unwieldy, obviously, but is really the only way to do this in a good typesafe manner.

You can reduce code at the expense of knowing the type of the data as follows:

```
for (TablePosition<DailySalesTableData, ?> pos : table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells()) {

    TableColumn<DailySalesTableData, ?> column = pos.getTableColumn();
    ObservableValue<?> obs = column.getCellObservableValue(pos.getRow());
    Object value = obs.getValue();

    // process value...
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. One thing I forgot to mention that, I want to do this operation on a specific column. Thank you very much.

Comment: So I would use the first version; you only need one `if` check and can presumably ignore other selected cells.

Comment: Yes. I have used the first version and also skipped the checking. Thanks